# Return specific type from IAsyncActionFilter

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of functions that are meant to have similar logic that i could wrap using attributes in c#, but the wrapper i'm currently trying to create should return a response value that is a custom type that simply represents a respond from server

Response class:

```cs
public class Response
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Method i want to wrap to (simple logic for demonstration purposes):

```cs
void SentRequest()
{
    Request(parameter: "simple text");
}
```

And lets say i want to wrap this method with attribute class, which can create a response value:

```cs
class StorageServiceFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private Response _response;

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        await next();

        _response.StatusCode = 200;
        _response.Message = "Upload successful";
    }
}
```

Now, is it possible to return my _response? I already know about `ActionExecutingContext.Result` property, but unfortunately it returns only `IActionResult` type, which is not suitable for my case.

**PS:**

Forgot to mention that `IAsyncActionFilter` has only the implementation for `Task OnActionExecutionAsync` that makes impossible to use `Task<T>` as a return type

Comment: I think you can use `ActionResult<T>`, in your case `ActionResult<Response>`.

Comment: @MikeMozhaev that doesn't make sense in case of async method (i forgot to mention that), so the only thing left is to use Task or Task<T>, but IAsyncActionFilter has only the implementation for `Task OnActionExecutionAsync`, and from then on returning anything else but Task will result an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the context returned by `await next()` and set the `Result` property. Something like this:

```
public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    var resultContext = await next();
    resultContext.Result = new ObjectResult(
        new Response() { StatusCode = 200, Message = "Upload successful" });
}
```

Please note that it will cause bypassing the remaining action filters:

> From [*ASP.NET Core In Action*](https://livebook.manning.com/book/asp-net-core-in-action/chapter-13/173) book:
>
> Setting the Result property on context short-circuits the pipeline.
> But, due to the position of the action filter stage, only the action
> method execution and later action filters are bypassed; all the other
> stages of the pipeline run as though the action had executed as
> normal.